# Regex: List of Mailadresses

Tags: regex

```
input:    name <hui.li@xxx.ch>; hans@dhdfhgdfgh <hans.dampf@xxxx>; 
Output:   e1@mail.com, e2@mail.com, e3@mail.com,e@mail.com
```

I want to erase the stuff between: `>;(?*)<` But my regex isn't working.

Comment: Your output seems unrelated to your input? What is your regex? How do you see that its not working?

Comment: i see it because 0 occurences were replaced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `>;(?*)<` is the Regex you tried, then the question mark is probably wrong. It has no special meaning. Try using `>;(.*)<` instead and see if thats what you wanted.

Comment: big thank Jens but i found a even nicer way to do it:
search for **(.*)<(.*)>;** and replace it with \2

Comment: @Simon: You should probably replace `.` with `[^<>]` in both cases to avoid accidentally replacing whole email entries.

Answer (score 0):

you should go another way. Instead of filtering the decoration you should write a regex, that matches only email addresses. Get the result as an array and join it with ", "

To find valid emails there are plenty of expressions out there. More ore less accurate. http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=email

Comment: *To find valid emails there are plenty of expressions out there.* -- You mean like [this one](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)?

Comment: Yepp, I once used this regex in a presentation as a good example of how to not use regex ;)   my favorite is: .+@.+(\.\w{2,4})   Not very accurate but simple.